# Spring thread stack size recommendation

Tags: java, spring

We have about 500~ spring beans in our application, and everytime we initialize the application (say weblogic restart or redeploy), spring bean creation will fail. The fail log contains thousands of spring call stack which is auto bean wiring part of spring code. We needs to enlarge thread stack size to about 3M to solve this problem.

Is there any recommendations about: 1. Setting thread stack size 2. Make spring not to call that deep in bean creation?

Comment: Why not split the application into different parts? 500 beans don't seem to be a good architectural design.

Comment: 1. Design Issue
2. Use auto-mapping feature

Comment: Either keep increasing your memory capacity, reduce memory usage or split your application into smaller module and install them on different VMs

Comment: We've already split application into several jars, but it's hard to separate it completely since every jar calls each other very frequently. Making it transform into web service is very unfavorable.